# How To Validate Multiple checkbox with angular 2

Tags: angular, multidimensional-array, angular2-forms

I'm new in angular how to used Custom validation for validate array of Multiple `checkbox` and I want a `button` should be disabled until a one `checkbox` checked .

Comment: We'll need to see some of the code you've tried, but the issue of validating a field based on values other than that of the input itself often requires a factory function, where you return the actual validator function based on whether or not a condition exists. Like the first example [here](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators), on the Angular guide

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to validate that at least one checkbox should be selected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43384804/how-to-validate-that-at-least-one-checkbox-should-be-selected)

Answer (score 1):

You have to subscribe to your checkbox control and react (enable/disable the button) to it when its value changes. Something like:

```
this.myForm.controls.isEnableCheckbox.valueChanges
.subscribe(checked => {
  if(checked){ // here you enable or disable the button or you can set a variable to do that...
    this.myForm.controls.buttonToEnable.enable(); 
  } else {
    this.myForm.controls.buttonToEnable.disable();
  }
});
```