# How to dynamically add formgroup with formcontrols to formgroup

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a very large form with many checkboxes, radios, textareas...
The whole form is dynamically generated from a DB.

At some points, I need to validate a group of checkboxes, in which at least one checkbox of that checkbox-group must be checked.
So I followed this manual: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54036689/11937089

My problem is, that the form group inside the form group must be generated dynamically.

I tried something like this:

```
this.outerForm.addControl('checkboxGroup' + (foo.id + ' ')), new FormGroup({}));

foo.forEach(bar => { get('checkboxGroup' + (foo.id + ' ')).addControl('checkbox'+ (foo.id + ' ') + (bar.id + ' ')), new FormControl(' ')); }
```

But I am pretty sure that this is completely wrong because addControl does not work with form groups and I have no idea how to reference that dynamic FormGroup checkboxGroup1 in the addControl-Part, `get` seems wrong.

```
outerform
--> textarea
--> checkboxGroup1
----->checkbox11
----->checkbox12
----->checkbox13
----->checkbox14
--> textarea
--> textarea
--> checkboxGroup2
----->checkbox21
----->checkbox22
----->checkbox23
----->checkbox24
```

Comment: Take a look at form builder and form array here https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#generating-form-controls-with-formbuilder , and this https://medium.com/aubergine-solutions/add-push-and-remove-form-fields-dynamically-to-formarray-with-reactive-forms-in-angular-acf61b4a2afe

Comment: The medium article was moved here:  https://auberginesolutions.com/blog/add-push-and-remove-form-fields-dynamically-to-formarray-with-reactive-forms-in-angular/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it myself, I was really close. 
`this.outerForm.addControl('checkboxGroup' + (foo.id + ' ')), new FormGroup({}));`
works just fine.

`get('checkboxGroup' + (foo.id + ' ')).addControl('checkbox'+ (foo.id + ' ') + (bar.id + ' ')), new FormControl(' '));`
was not complete.

`(this.outerForm.get('checkboxGroup' + (foo.id + ' ')) as any).addControl('checkbox'+ (foo.id + ' ') + (bar.id + ' ')), new FormControl(' '));`
did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Try somthing like this with **formArray**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-array-example

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, FormArray, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="form">
      <input type="checkbox" formControlName="published"> Published
      <div *ngIf="form.controls.published.value">

        <h2>Credentials</h2>
        <button (click)="addCreds()">Add</button>

        <div formArrayName="credentials" *ngFor="let creds of form.controls.credentials?.value; let i = index">
          <ng-container [formGroupName]="i">
            <input placeholder="Username" formControlName="username">
            <input placeholder="Password" formControlName="password">
          </ng-container>
        </div>

      </div>
    </form>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent  {
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      published: true,
      credentials: this.fb.array([]),
    });
  }

  addCreds() {
    const creds = this.form.controls.credentials as FormArray;
    creds.push(this.fb.group({
      username: '',
      password: '',
    }));
  }
}
```

Comment: Please demonstrate the proposed solution in your answer. Links are volatile.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @angular/forms. So, you can use FormGroup, FormArray, FormControl.
Just for example please have a look at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3x3tme?file=src/app/hello.component.ts